# textarea alternative using javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I love how the textarea can be resized by placing the mouse on the slanted lines in the lower right hand corner and dragging the mouse. I am wanting to add css styles to text and this cannot be achieved with a textarea. Does anyone know a way to emulate the textarea resizing using another DOM element? This way, I can add my CSS styles to the text and whatever else i place inside. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/).

Comment: Thanks Niels. I'm looking into this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find that you can apply css to a text-area just like you can with any other element. Theres only two elements which are funny with css, thats file uploader and select.

For example, see http://codepen.io/cshaw/pen/YyVxRE for an example of a text-area styled with basic css.

```
<style>
textarea {
border: 1px solid black;
background: green;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
}
</style>
<textarea name="youtextarea">
  SOME CONTENT
</textarea>
```

Or if it must me a re sizable div see http://codepen.io/cshaw/pen/zvwdbB

```
<style>
div {
resize: both;
border: 1px solid #222;
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
background: #222;
color: #999; 
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<div>Resizable Div</div>
```

Or pop over to https://www.chris-shaw.com for more.

Comment: Thanks for responding Christopher, I should have been more in depth. I will be applying dynamic styles to the text and this cannot be achieved with a textarea because it doesn't have the innerHTML attribute like a textbox or div.

Comment: See the modified version, this should cover your needs, basically treads a div as a textarea

Comment: Thanks Christopher...this works great

Answer (score 0):

did you try the *css* **resize** property ??

```css
div {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 300px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer does not support the resize property.</p>

<div>Let the user resize both the height and the width of this div element.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This gives the lines in the corner..I checked it in Opera/Chrome/Firefox...IE/Edge are horrible browsers, so this doesn't work in them. Thanks Angry Coder!